# Is there a way to get HTML5 Builder to get Turkish character encoding right in Android projects?

Tags: android, character-encoding, radphp, html5builder

First I edit the `MPage encoding`. Then I add some mobile components on design view.

I populate their `caption/list properties` with text including `Turkish characters`.

However in the template view `HTML5 Builder` does not show these characters correctly.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is it not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for UTF-8 support are described in the **[UTF-8 Setup](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/UTF-8_Setup)** page in the documentation:

- **Change the PHP encoding.** See the documentation for details on how your *Home → Options → PHP* page is meant to look like.
- **Change the file encoding.** From the *Code* view of your page, right-click anywhere in the code and select *File Format → UTF8*.
- **Change the (M)Page encoding.** From the *Design* view, use the Object Inspector to set the *Encoding* property to *Unicode | utf-8*.

If your system uses a **Turkish locale**, it should work. On Windows 7: *Start → Control Panel → Change Display Language → Administrative (tab) → Language for non-Unicode programs*

If with everything, the template preview still shows the worng characters, make sure you have the following code in your template, in the <head></head>:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it more depends on the browser you are showing it with later. If you want to pack it as an android app and your phone supports turkish characters it should be totally fine to view it inside an webview.

Answer (score 0):

After a few changes in encodings and restarting the IDE, the issue was resolved partly. Template view still does not recognize the encoding in a way. But I can deploy the application to virtual device or real device without any issues related to encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before ,,try to change the system language
for example : windows 7
control panel > Region and language > Administrative > Change system locale
and tell me :)